# Emulating Cortex A12 on QEMU

Tags: qemu

Is it possible to emulate Cortex A12 on QEMU?
What `-machine` should I choose?
I tried to do that with `versatileab`, `versatilepb`, `vexpress-a9`, `vexpress-a15`, in versatileab/pb I get `qemu: fatal: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x80008000`.
on vexpress-a9/15 the qemu become stuck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we don't currently provide an emulation of Cortex-A12. However the Cortex-A15 should be close enough for most guests not to care.

In general you cannot just use '-cpu something' on an arbitrary QEMU ARM board model. These boards are usually models of SoCs or embedded development boards that never had any kind of pluggable CPU, and they are not designed to work with any random CPU model plugged into them.

If you want a Cortex-A15 then I would suggest either 'virt' or 'vexpress-a15'. Either way, you need to make sure your guest code is built to run on that board and that you pass it either a BIOS image or a kernel to run. (Unlike qemu-system-x86_64, it will not automatically boot a BIOS if run with no arguments.)